timing issue with monaco script
for some reason the component does not initiate the monaco script initial data and available data sometimes.
if i refresh the page where the component is, it works.
I think it might be a timing issue, or that i am creating more than one instance at a time but i cant figure it out.
I found this related stackoverflow but no luck implement its solution:
Flutter web project with javascript modules that use requireJS (Monaco editor in Flutter web)
I event tried adding a delay for after the monaco loader loads and before sending the initial data, that didnt work
code1::
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:ui_web';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import '../../../core/notifiers/form_page_notifier.dart';

class ScriptColumn extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> column;
  final Function(String, dynamic) on_changed;

  ScriptColumn({
    Key? key,
    required this.column,
    required this.on_changed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScriptColumnState createState() => _ScriptColumnState();
}

class _ScriptColumnState extends ConsumerState<ScriptColumn> {
  late html.IFrameElement _iframeElement;
  bool _is_loading = true;
  bool _editor_ready = false;
  StreamSubscription? _messageSubscription;
  bool _isDisposed = false; // Track if widget has been disposed

  Map<String, dynamic> objects = {
    "current": {"sys_name": "aaa"} // initial available data
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("\n_ScriptColumnState*()");

    _initializeEditor();

    // Listen for messages from the iframe and handle them appropriately
    _messageSubscription = html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      if (_isDisposed || !mounted) return;  // Ensure widget is mounted and not disposed before processing the event

        if (event.data['type'] == 'editorContent') {
          final editorContent = event.data['content'] ?? "";
          widget.on_changed(widget.column['sys_id'], editorContent);
        } else if (event.data['type'] == 'editorReady') {
          print("EDITOR IS READY");
          _editor_ready = true;
          _updateEditorContent();
        }
      
    });
  }

  void _initializeEditor() {
    _iframeElement = html.IFrameElement()
      ..src = 'monaco_editor.html'
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..style.height = '100%'
      ..style.width = '100%';

    _is_loading = false;

    if (mounted && !_isDisposed) {
      setState(() {}); // Only call setState if the widget is still mounted and not disposed
    }
  }

  void _updateEditorContent() {
    // Check if the widget is mounted and editor is ready
    if (_isDisposed || !mounted || !_editor_ready) return;

    try {
      final current = ref.read(form_page_provider).record;
      final currentText = current[widget.column['sys_name']] ?? "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
      // print("currentText: ${currentText}");

      final message = {
        'type': 'updateContent',
        'content': currentText.toString(),
        'objects': jsonEncode(objects),
      };
      print("sending updateContent");
      _iframeElement.contentWindow?.postMessage(message, '*');
      
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle any exception that occurs when trying to update the editor content
      print("Error updating editor content: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ScriptColumn oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (_isDisposed || !mounted) return; // Prevent updates if the widget is disposed

    if (_editor_ready) {
      _updateEditorContent();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isDisposed = true; // Mark the widget as disposed
    _messageSubscription?.cancel(); // Cancel the listener when the widget is disposed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final current = ref.watch(form_page_provider.select((data) => data.record[widget.column['sys_name']]));

    if (_is_loading) {
      return BasicLoader(); // Show loader while iframe is being initialized
    }

    // Update editor content if there are changes in the provider data
    if (_editor_ready && !_isDisposed) {
      _updateEditorContent();
    }

    // Register the iframe as a view in Flutter
    platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'monaco-editor-container',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: 'monaco-editor-container');
  }
}

code2:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.47.0/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #container { 
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        let editor;
        let receivedObjects = {};
        let isEditorBlurred = false;

        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.47.0/min/vs' }});
        require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
            editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
                value: "// loading ...",
                language: 'javascript',
                theme: 'vs-light',
                automaticLayout: true
            });

            editor.onDidFocusEditorText(() => {
                isEditorBlurred = false;
            });

            editor.onDidBlurEditorText(() => {
                isEditorBlurred = true;
                sendEditorContent(); // Update content when editor loses focus
            });

            monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
                provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
                    const textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange({
                        startLineNumber: 1, 
                        startColumn: 1, 
                        endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, 
                        endColumn: position.column
                    });
                    const match = textUntilPosition.match(/(\w+)$/);
                    const wordToReplace = match ? match[1] : '';
                    
                    const customSuggestions = generateSuggestions(receivedObjects, '', wordToReplace);
                    const builtInSuggestions = generateBuiltInSuggestions(wordToReplace);
                    
                    return { 
                        suggestions: [...customSuggestions, ...builtInSuggestions],
                        range: {
                            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                            startColumn: position.column - wordToReplace.length,
                            endColumn: position.column
                        }
                    };
                }
            });

            // Notify parent that the editor is ready
            window.parent.postMessage({ type: 'editorReady' }, '*');
        });

        function sendEditorContent() {
            if (isEditorBlurred) {
                window.parent.postMessage({
                    type: 'editorContent',
                    content: editor.getValue()
                }, '*');
            }
        }

        function generateSuggestions(obj, prefix = '', wordToReplace = '') {
            return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
                const fullKey = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key;
                const suggestions = [{
                    label: fullKey,
                    kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Field,
                    insertText: fullKey,
                    detail: JSON.stringify(value)
                }];
                if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                    suggestions.push(...generateSuggestions(value, fullKey, wordToReplace));
                }
                return suggestions;
            });
        }

        function generateBuiltInSuggestions(wordToReplace) {
            const builtIns = [
                {
                    label: 'JSON.stringify',
                    kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                    insertText: 'JSON.stringify',
                    detail: 'Convert a JavaScript object to a JSON string'
                },
                {
                    label: 'JSON.parse',
                    kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                    insertText: 'JSON.parse',
                    detail: 'Parse a JSON string into a JavaScript object'
                }
            ];

            return builtIns.filter(item => item.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(wordToReplace.toLowerCase()));
        }

        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.data && event.data.type === 'updateContent') {
                console.log("update content received!")
                editor.setValue(event.data.content);
                if (event.data.objects) {
                    receivedObjects = JSON.parse(event.data.objects);
                }
            } else if (event.data && event.data.type === 'getEditorContent') {
                sendEditorContent();
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

output::
_ScriptColumnState*()
2
sending updateContent
EDITOR IS READY
sending updateContent
EDITOR IS READY
sending updateContent

below is the dummy code to get all the code to work::
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
import 'script_column.dart'; // Import your ScriptColumn class file

// Define a provider to simulate state management
final formPageProvider = Provider((ref) {
  // Simulated record data
  return {
    'example_sys_name': 'Initial content of the editor',
  };
});

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Script Column Example')),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context, ref, child) {
                  // Use ScriptColumn here
                  return ScriptColumn(
                    column: {'sys_id': '123', 'sys_name': 'example_sys_name'},
                    on_changed: (id, content) {
                      print('Content for $id changed: $content');
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

